# Como identificar o tipo de dado retornado de um controller?

Tags: php, laravel

Observei que ao criar um controller no Laravel ele informa que alguns métodos terão como retorno um objeto `\Illuminate\Http\Response`.

Utilizei um dd() no final do método e vi o seguinte retorno: `\Illuminate\View\View` e em outro método `\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse`

Neste caso, ao documentar os métodos devo considerar sempre: `\Illuminate\Http\Response` ou posso inserir o objeto visualizado no output do método `dd()`?

Comment: Mostre um exemplo da documentação ... Não consegui visualizar sua duvida.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) do PHP

```
if ($objeto instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Response) {
    ... faz algo aqui ...
} else if ($objeto instanceof \Illuminate\View\View) {
    ... faz algo aqui ...
}
```